# SAML Single Logout Service not working in ADFS when integrated as IDP in KeyCloak

Tags: keycloak, saml, adfs

I'm experiencing an issue with Single Logout while integrating **ADFS** & **KeyCloak**.

I'm working on integrating ADFS as an ***IDP*** in KeyCloak. I've configured KeyCloak as a ***Relying Party Trust*** in ADFS. Logging in through the ADFS login form works fine, but I face a problem when trying to log out. It redirects me to `https://<Host Name>/adfs/ls/`, showing this screen:

[image: ADFS Error Page]

ADFS logs indicate that the Single Logout Service isn't configured correctly, although I've added a SAML logout URL as follows.

[image: ADFS logout URL]

**ADFS log:**

*An error occurred during the processing of the SAML logout request.*

*Additional Data Caller identity:
Logout initiator identity: https://keycloak-host/auth/realms/adfs-integration Error message: MSIS7083: Cannot find the supported SingleLogoutService endpoint for session participant 'https://keycloak-host/auth/realms/adfs-integration'. Exception details:
User Action Ensure that the single logout service is configured properly for this relying party trust or claims provider trust in the AD FS configuration database.*

Here are the configuration URLs of KeyCloak:
[image: KeyCloak redirect URIs]

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone could provide insights into what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing.